# Facebook Api: limit parameter

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to read a facebook group feed and set the limit to 100.

My php code:

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '<myappid>';
$config['secret'] = '<mysecret>';
$config['fileUpload'] = false;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$feed = $facebook->api("/<groupid>/feed");
```

How do I set the limit to 100 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set limit field.Maximum is 100 according to doc.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed.

The following example is for your reference.

```
/feed?limit=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the limit would be done like this:

```
$feed = $facebook->api("/<groupid>/feed?limit=100");
```

Keep in mind that there are access restrictions depending on the type of the group.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#paging
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#limits
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed